# Retrieve 'second to last' data of every group

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to retrieve 'second to last' data of every group . Currently ,the code as below, using 'group_modify' twice. Is there any available function for this?  (how to simply current code)?  Thanks!

*The wished result in the red rectangular in attached image.*

```
library(dplyr)

test_data <- data.frame(category=c("a","a","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"),
                        value=c(1.72,0.32,0.22,1.29,-0.49,0.61,1.24,0.58,0.26))


test_data %>%  arrange(category ) %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  group_modify(~tail(.x,2)) %>% 
  group_modify(~head(.x,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `nth(value, -2)`, which gives second last of each group:

```
library(dplyr)

  test_data %>%  
    arrange(category ) %>% 
    group_by(category) %>% 
    summarise(value1 = nth(value, -2))
```

```
  category value1
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 a          1.29
2 b         -0.49
3 c          0.61
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to remove first one ,  just want to single one from every gorup which in th 'second to last'

Comment: could you please show the expected output?

Comment: Thanks , i eidited my post ,please refer to attached image

Comment: Thanks, funciont [nth] is waht I want

Answer (score 3):

You can extract `n() - 1` row in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

test_data %>% group_by(category) %>% slice(n()-1) %>% ungroup

#  category value
#  <chr>    <dbl>
#1 a         1.29
#2 b        -0.49
#3 c         0.61
```

Answer (score 1):

If a list output is acceptable this works:

```
test_data %>% 
  arrange(category) %>% 
  group_split(category) %>% 
  map(. %>% slice(nrow(.)-1))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  category value
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 a         1.29

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  category value
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 b        -0.49

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  category value
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 c         0.61
```

Comment: "map(. %>% slice(nrow(.)-1))" this usage is great for me to learn  .Thanks.